# Powershell always exiting with exit code 1

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2012

I'm having an issue on multiple machines for one customer: when running any PowerShell script, the process always exits with exitcode `1`, unless an exitcode is explicitly specified in the script (e.g. `exit 0`).

- As far as I know, the process should exit with exitcode `0` when the script ran successfully, and when I run this on my own machine, or any server outside of this customer, the exitcode is `0`:

  ```
  # Run something to set current errorlevel to 0
  > ver
    Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]

  # Show what's in my test script
  > type test.ps1
    Write-Host testing

  > echo %ERRORLEVEL%
    0

  # Run the testscript
  > powershell -NoProfile -NonInteractive -NoLogo ./test.ps1
    testing

  # Print errorlevel
  > echo %ERRORLEVEL%
    1
  ```

Does anyone know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: PowerShell provides many ways to do X or Y. You choose which makes the best case for your target need. Base troubleshooting, says, if all is well in one environment vs another, then the issue is with the failing environment, not your code. Meaning, something in the failing environment is impacting your code and only you can determine what that is by trying different approaches in each. See these options to validate in your environments: [PowerShell return value, exit code, or ErrorLevel equivalent](https://www.saotn.org/powershell-return-value-exit-code-or-errorlevel-equivalent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating to the latest version of powershell, the issue was solved.

Answer (score 2):

*(Continuing from my comment)*

***These are two completely separate things:***

- ```
  > type test.ps1
    Write-Host testing

  > echo %ERRORLEVEL%
    0
  ```

  This is just using `Get-Content` (if you were in the PowerShell console, not `cmd.exe`) to display the text in the script:

  - thus command being run here is `Get-Content`, not your script code
  - unless you are doing this at a cmd prompt, then it's DOS type internal command, not Powershell at all
- ```
  > powershell -NoProfile -NonInteractive -NoLogo ./test.ps1
    testing

  > echo %ERRORLEVEL%
    1
  ```

  - This is actually running the script, by calling `powershell.exe` from `cmd.exe`, and is not an apples-to-apples comparison, leading you to false results.
  - Executing `echo %ERRORLEVEL%` in a PS shell is meaningless, as PS has no idea what `%ERRORLEVEL%` is in that use context; to see the last error, you use the PS system error variables, not `CMD.exe`/DOS stuff.

The code you posted is you doing all things in `cmd.exe`, not PowerShell; `ver` is DOS internal command, not a PowerShell command:

- ```
  ver /?

    Displays the Windows version.
  ```

  ```
  Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_OperatingSystem

    SystemDirectory     Organization BuildNumber RegisteredUser SerialNumber            Version
    ---------------     ------------ ----------- -------------- ------------            -------
    C:\WINDOWS\system32              19043       Test00         00000-00000-00000-AAOEM 10.0.19043
  ```
- Just the version:

  ```
  (Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_OperatingSystem).Version

    10.0.19043
  ```

See also: [Returning an exit code from a PowerShell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50200325/returning-an-exit-code-from-a-powershell-script)